# Mean Value Theorem Problems

Tags: derivatives

Consider the graph of the function $f(x)= x^2-x-12$.

a) Write the equation of the secant line in point slope form joining the points at $x=-2$ and $x=4$.

b) Use the Mean value theorem to determine a point c in the interval $(-2,4)$ such that the tangent line at $c$ is parallel to the secant line.

c) Find the equation of the tangent line at $c$ in point slope form.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I first tried to find the slope by inputting values x =-2 and x=-4 into the equation. I got -11 as the slope. (-30-(-36)/(4+2) = -11. Then I took the derivative and set it it to -11. -11=-2x+1. I tried to plug in the values -2 and 4 into the x and I got nothing because -11 didn't equal those values

Comment: It looks like you got $f(-2)$ and $f(4)$ both wrong...

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x^2-x-12\implies f(-2)=-6, f(4)=0$.

(a) Slope of secant joining $(-2,-6),(4,0)$ is $\displaystyle\frac{0-(-6)}{4-(-2)}=1$.Equation of this secant in slope point form is $(y-0)=1\cdot (x-4)\implies y=x-4$.

(b) Now by LMVT, $\exists \ c \in (-2,4)$ such that $f'(c)= 1\implies 2c-1=1\implies c=1$.

(c) $f(1)=1-1-12=-12,f'(1)=1$.Equation of tangent to $f$ at $x=c=1$ is $y-(-12)=1(x-1)\implies y=x-13$.

Comment: thank you so much!